# Cordova footer position fixed IOS11

Tags: cordova, footer, ios11, fixed, phonegap

I've created a Cordova/Phonegap website and every works fine, except on a iPhone X with IOS 11. The problem is that the footer is position fixed at the bottom but it doesn't stay there the whole time. If I scroll down on the app the footer stands still for a second and then gets to the bottom. The problem only appears on that phone, not on a Android or Windows.

```
.footer-result
 background-color: $color-4
 bottom: 0px
 clear: both
 color: $color-1
 display: block
 font-family: "ff-kava-web-pro", sans-serif
 font-size: 1.3em
 left: 0
 right: 0
 padding: 10px 20px
 position: fixed !important
 width: 100%
 z-index: 9
 transform: translateZ(0)
```

[example image app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY8rh.jpg)

Comment: Can we see your DOM where .footer-result lives ?

Comment: If you download Phonegap on IOS 11 and open this URL: 192.168.123.48:3000. It works perfect if you go to this by website, but not by Phonegap.

Comment: URL doesn't work for me - maybe because of a firewall - I don't know :)

Comment: Basically I'm interested to see what div ( or stack of divs ) your .footer-result lives in. Sometimes the fixed elements on iOS don't work well if they are nested inside other divs ....

Comment: You can try: http://3951cac3.ngrok.io/

Answer (score 2):

Okay - lots of CSS files in there - so hard to quickly debug, but I think if you move your fixed footer element to be a simple child of "body" or maybe div class "views" then the element should truly fix to the bottom. I have seen fixed elements in iOS jump about or position incorrectly when their parent divs have absolute or relative positions.
Also you might want to look at this page:
https://stanko.github.io/ios-safari-scoll-position-fixed/

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for you reply! CSS has already got the transform property, but I doesn't help.

Comment: Okay - in this case I would recommend trying the footer div as direct a child of body and see if it fixes the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution.